# How to edit and cope with low quality posts

Tags: discussion, edits

I've taken on the task of making edits to low quality posts as a way to relax and help keep the SE sites looking professional. One thing that has been aggravating me during this process is the abundance of low quality posts where people refuse to:

- [Use paragraphs](https://superuser.com/posts/1788420/revisions)
- [Capitalize the word "I"](https://superuser.com/posts/1790233/revisions)
- Use punctuation

If people who refuse to capitalize the word "I", or use paragraphs, why should any of us bother to take time to correct this shortcoming?

Is there not a standard for posting on SE sites where posts like this are rejected on grounds of refusal to use capitalization, paragraphs and proper spelling? In my option, these types of low quality posts tend to tarnish the reputation (and the hard work), of the people who put into making this a professional looking environment.

Comment: If you don't enjoy editing low quality posts, stop doing it.

Comment: What you're saying (looking at lots of posts with basic grammar errors like not capitalizing 'I' is pretty annoying) is true, but I don't think there's really any way to categorize any given post as lazy or not. I guess there is a review queue called triage in SO, may be that can be used for users to vote on whether a post is 'lazy' before it actually goes to other users for edit reviews

Comment: @ElementsinSpace I do enjoy it most of the time. I'm asking if there are standards that should prevail, or whether we just accept it and downvote without editing.

Comment: I think we should give any user the benefit of doubt before claiming they are just lazy. May be they wanted to post a quick question first (so that at least the question gets out there, sometimes it can take hours or even days before a question is viewed by someone who knows the answer) and would edit it after some time to clarify grammar, or may be someone was doing it on mobile and it was too annoying to fix small things like these. There can be any number of reasons besides just 'lazy'. I would  take this an opportunity to get quick reps or badge

Comment: or take a quick break and come back to editing if it gets too annoying in one sitting

Comment: Standards should prevail. If I come across these in the future I will simply downvote them then and not waste my time.

Comment: That's one option. It's completely your decision. Your time is also valuable, you should get to decide which post gets your time. But from what I understand downvoting will cost you points as well (-1 per downvote I think) so I would just skip the post in that case. Why should you lose rep for someone else's laziness

Comment: You are right. Waste of time and rep. I guess there is nothing worth doing about it.

Comment: As said by others here these issues might not be due to laziness. One of the very plausible scenario is that the person posting is just not familiar with Markdown (someone unfamiliar might think just one newline should be enough to create a new paragraph). As for the capitalization of "I" or punctuation the user might not be very proficient at English.

Comment: Your first example *does* use paragraphs… they just didn't come out as the user intended. Most newbies have no idea that you need two spaces before a return to get a simple new line. Why not tell them about it in a comment? *'teach a man to fish'*

Comment: @Tetsujin Sorry, but I don't see any paragraphs there at all (just one big long paragraph). I'm not sure how you can surmise that someone didn't know about the two returns. I mean, did I miss something that shows that's what happened in my example? (I'm open to being wrong here, but I'm not sure what you are using as an indicator). Also, when people post, I'm fairly sure that they can see there are no paragraphs when the question goes live. I agree with your philosophy 100% about teaching people =)

Comment: You need to look at it in edit - https://superuser.com/posts/1788420/edit/dd631f45-369c-4ef1-b249-4ff4955269f7 It's full of new lines, if not actual double-return paragraphs. That's just a style thing, imo. I use [double space] new lines all the time in QAs here, but only true [double return] paragraphs to better separate ideas. I get the feeling that newbies when they first post can see one return doesn't actually make a new line, but don't extrapolate that 2 returns would work, & certainly no-one's ever going to guess 2 spaces + return will work, so they just leave it as-is.

Comment: More "tried & failed" than "couldn't be bothered". The second example just demonstrates low literacy level to me. Run-on sentences, stream-of-consciousness rather than structured thinking/writing. High-school level, I'd guess.

Comment: @Tetsujin ah yes, would you look at that. Very good. So, not the perfect example of laziness there, but more about formatting issues. I still struggle sometimes to get spacing right in SE sites, but this is good that you pointed this out. Thank you.

Comment: Re [the first example](https://superuser.com/posts/1788420/revisions): A valid excuse is that they are used to platforms where ***a single newline*** renders (clearer [in the source view](https://superuser.com/revisions/dd631f45-369c-4ef1-b249-4ff4955269f7/view-source)). It doesn't render in Markdown (like HTML). But write-only is not an excuse (never looking at final (rendered) result). Another valid excuse is they are used to platforms where you can't change anything after the initial posting.

Comment: Re *"These types of low quality posts really trash the reputation"*: Yes, it does. Just look at the average search result involving Stack Overflow. It is ***embarrassing*** for the profession (and will probably ultimately lower the salaries for all). But there is *nothing* you can do (the volume is way too high). Stack Overflow (and probably most of the rest of the network) has been in [Eternal September](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-questions/) mode for the last 13 years.

Comment: [You missed a few.](https://superuser.com/posts/1790233/revisions)

Comment: You can't make people not be lazy (or whatever actual issue led to things that make you think they're being lazy) and we're never going to get to a point where new users post perfect questions the very first time. For what it's worth, I see plenty of _answers_ demonstrating the same kind of laziness and low quality, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's important to distinguish between *low quality posts*, and *posts with low quality spelling/formatting*.
The latter are definitely worth editing if you enjoy that (I certainly do).  But the former are probably not worth your time or energy; skip these and look for the latter.

I imagine that one reason for uncapitalised I's, missing punctuation, and paragraphs breaks, etc. is that some users are "typing" with their phones, and they just don't know how to use *Shift*, *Carriage Return*, or other punctuation — not much of an excuse if you ask me, but it seems like a reasonable theory.

---

One "solution" to this problem was trialed on Stack Overflow last week: the Formatting Assistant Experiment (see [We are seeking functional feedback for the formatting assistant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425162/we-are-seeking-functional-feedback-for-the-formatting-assistant)).  Some results were ... interesting (amusingly bad).

Comment: Those are definitely good distinctions, as spelling, grammar and formatting aren't always something that get in the way of a good idea or call for help. If the problem is with mobiles, perhaps there is a way for the system to catch on to that and correct the errors.

Comment: The Formatting Assistant could probably do that effectively if they made it less ambitious, (much less ambitious).

Comment: Another "solution" is *Peter Mortensen* (AKA *This_is_NOT_a_forum*), who uses some kind of software to edit posts robotically. Personally, I don't like this approach either; "good" editing requires careful judgement and more skill than can be written into a script. But, it does clean up this kind of problem in some of the worst posts (whether they deserve it or not).

Answer (score 24):

"If it does not give you joy... let it go"

If editing is making you get *angry* at people - it is time to take a break, or focus on the more fun aspects of the site.

I'd also point out most of us are not professionals at Q&A, and arguably even the people who work here aren't. We just do our best.

Answer (score 14):

I applaud you for having "taken on the task of making edits to low quality posts as a way to relax and help keep the SE sites looking professional".  I do the same.

However, I think you should not label posters as lazy.  If you think a post is not useful simply downvote it.  If you wish to volunteer time to edit or comment instead, then do so.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is really no excuse for not capitalizing "I" unless your caps lock is busted. I'm not sure what to say about the lack of paragraphs though. I applaud you too for taking that on. Its grunt work at best, but at least it presents the site in a way that is more professional.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Not all users are fluent English speakers and many languages do not capitalize the first person pronouns... in general, it's best to avoid judging people's spelling and grammar. It can be frustrating to constantly see issues in posts but, at the same time, you can choose who to help - there's plenty to edit, so be choosy. If seeing lowercase "I"s makes you grumpy, then find another post to improve - or come up with fun stories about why they can't use the capital letter. :)

Answer (score 5):

I agree that there is an imbalance between what the system rejects automatically (you can't use the same title as an existing question; many common words are prohibited in titles; you can't post more code than text) and what it lazily (as it were) permits (posts with no punctuation, like you note; posts with the same text repeated for filler or annoyance; posts with no English words). But I don't think we want more of these artificial and rather stupid boundaries which sometimes make it hard to get a post accepted at all.

Your conclusion that you could simply downvote posts which exhibit lack of effort is basically correct, or at least acceptable. However, I would caution you to look below the surface. Some users actually have useful and interesting questions below the noise and bad grammar. Penalizing bad *exposition* at the expense of the possible *substance* seems lazy, too.

(However, those cases are exceptions, and often enough, sloppy formatting goes hand in hand with sloppy problem articulation and sloppy thinking.)

Comment: Oh I can see the fog through the trees, and most often take the time to make the post as palatable as possible. It's the lack of this same effort by the authors that irks me.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited the question to be more friendly and properly reflect what I meant to convey. All references to 'laziness' have been removed as I see now that there may be several other factors that lead to these shortcomings which include:

- User is ESL
- User is on mobile app

I will also take the advice of the few users who suggested not to bother with editing these posts if they arouse negative feelings on my behalf.